# Angular Scope com apply no ng-init

Tags: angularjs

Olá, tenho o seguinte problema, tenho essa função que recebe dados de um banco de dados interno e armazena as informações no `$scope.dados`, eu consigo mostrar os valores de `$scope.dados` normalmente na tela.

O problema vem na hora de usar algum valor do `$scope.dados` no `ng-init`, no código abaixo eu consigo trazer um valor do banco e exibi-lo no `input`, mas caso eu queira salvar

```
selecionou($stateParams.id);
function selecionou(id) {
       $pouchDB.get(id).then(function(resp){
       $scope.dados = resp;
       $scope.$apply();
    });
 }

{{formulario.valor}}

<input type="text" placeholder="" ng-value="dados.valor" ng-model="formulario.valor" ng-init="formulario.valor = dados.valor">
```

Comment: o ng-init é disparado sempre o html está sendo construido, ou seja nesse momento seu variavel 'dados.valor' ainda não tem valor, logo que a chamada do servidor é uma chamada async e assim sua variavel dados.valor ainda não foi preenchida com o retorno do servidor.

Comment: Por qual motivo você está usando o `ng-init`? É obrigatório isso? Ou você pode recorrer a outro método para obter o mesmo resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

porquê usar ng-init?

você pode simplesmente:

```
function selecionou(id) {
       $pouchDB.get(id).then(function(resp){
       $scope.dados = resp;
       formulario.valor = resp.valor;
       $scope.$apply();
    });
}
    <input type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="formulario.valor">
```

e aí fazer o bind no formuario.valor. ng-value só faz sentido em `<option>` ou `input[radio]`

ou pode fazer o bind diretmente no dados.valor

```
function selecionou(id) {
           $pouchDB.get(id).then(function(resp){
           $scope.dados = resp;
           $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
    <input type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="dados.valor" >
```

Comment: veja, eu tenho esse input que vai ser do tipo readonly, ele recebe um valor que vem do banco, e pode mudar o valor através de um botão, quando muda o valor eu preciso pegar o novo valor para poder enviar para salvar no banco novalmente, porém não consigo fazer com que ele reconheça que o "dados.valor" recebeu um novo valor ele fica como undefined, aqui você pode ver mais ou menos o que é que estou tentando fazer http://jsfiddle.net/c7bsrenu/24/

Comment: mas o botão não muda o dados.valor também? Veja, se você tem o input (readonly ou não) com o ng-model, mudando o valor, o input mostra essa alteração. Para gravar no banco de novo é só pegar o dados.valor e gravar

Answer (score 1):

Adicione no ng-init a chamada para sua função (selecionou) nesse, assim que o ng-init for construido ele vai disparar sua função para que dispara a chamada no servidor, e preenche seu objeto que está utilizado no ng-model.

OBS: o ng-init é disparado sempre o html está sendo construido, ou seja nesse momento seu variavel 'dados.valor' ainda não tem valor, logo que a chamada do servidor é uma chamada async e assim sua variavel dados.valor ainda não foi preenchida com o retorno do servidor.

```
function selecionou() {
       $pouchDB.get($stateParams.id).then(function(resp){
       $scope.dados = resp;
    });
 }


<input type="text" placeholder="" ng-value="dados.valor"   ng-model="formulario.valor" ng-init="selecionou()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Nunca use o `ng-init`, a forma como você o usa é exatamente o que é recomendado não fazer, existem poucos usos do `ng-init` que são considerados apropriados, no geral o recomendado é inicializar os valores no Controller.

No seu caso ainda existe um outro erro que é o uso do `ng-value`, ele não foi feito para ser usado em uma tag `input` exceto pelo `input[type=radio]` e pela tag `option`, para o valor de tags `input` apenas o `ng-model` é necessário.

Então os dados deveriam ser iniciados em seu controller em vez do `ng-init`, e tudo depende de como vem os seus dados, simplificando poderia ser

```
selecionou($stateParams.id);

function selecionou(id) {
   $pouchDB.get(id).then(function(resp){
       $scope.dados = resp;
    });
}
```

Considerando que você esteja usando um wrapper do PouchDB para o AngularJS então você não deveria precisar chamar o `$scope.apply()`

> OBS: não tenho conhecimentos sobre o funcionamento do PouchDB, pelo seu código estou considerando que ele retorna um objeto com os dados que precisa editar no formulário

O seu template deveria ser basicamente

```
{{dados.valor}} 
<input type="text" ng-model="dados.valor" />
```

Como nós usamos o `$scope.dados` para guardar o resultado da consulta então podemos também usa-lo diretamente no binding, qualquer valor que o usuário alterar será automaticamente alterado no objeto.

E só lembrando que quando for alterar o valor por javascript nunca deve alterar diretamente no `input`, deve alterar apenas os valores no seu `$scope` e deixar o angular atualizar os bindings automaticamente.